Paginating with sort and direction
Cakephp Version: 5.0.10
Hi,
Tickets Controller - The Process
The page is initially loaded and I initialise the limit from the database and store in a setter with:
 $this->setLimit($user->results_per_page->respp_ticket);

I also hard code the sort and direction and store in setters with:
$this->setSort('Tickets.date_created');
$this->setDirection('desc');

I paginate the query with.
$tickets = $this->paginate($query);
$this->set(compact('tickets'));

I apply the limit, sort and direction to the query like this:
$this->paginate = [
    'limit' => $this->getLimit(),
    'order' => [
        $this->getSort() => $this->getDirection(),
    ],
];

$tickets = $this->paginate($query);
$this->set(compact('tickets')); 

The limit, sort and direction have been applied to the query correctly. And you can sort on any column correctly.
The page numbers however do not contain the sort and direction in the url.
QUESTION
Is there anyway to pass the sort and direction in the url via the paginations page numbers so I can initialise them in the tickets controller after I click the page numbers?
What else I've tried
If I initialise the pagination like the following the sort and direction are in the url when the page numbers are clicked.
$this->paginate = [
    'limit' => $this->getLimit(),
    'sort' => $this->getSort(),
    'direction' => $this->getDirection(),
];

But this error is displayed in the view:
Warning (512) : Passing query options as paginator settings is no longer supported. Use a custom finder through the finder config or pass a SelectQuery instance to paginate(). Extra keys found are: sort, direction.
QUESTION
How do I configure a finder to initialise the sort and direction?
Thanks Zenzs

Instead of multipasting everywhere, best to follow the conversation then @ https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/passing-query-options-as-paginator-settings-is-no-longer-supported/12193/7

Look at the dates. I posted on here first then 2 days later when I did'nt get an answer I posted on the cake forum. And I only posted on here and the cake forum, not everywhere.

Fair enough. I hope you managed your pagination in the end with the tips you got.
